# update file descriptor after os.rename()

Tags: python

What is the best way to handle `Bad file descriptor` errors after calling `os.rename()` in the following manner?

```
f = open('foo.txt', 'rw')
os.rename(f.name, f.name + ".bak")
```

In the file system there is no longer a `foo.txt` but instead a `foo.txt.bak`

However..

```
f.name
```

gives `foo.txt` instead of `foo.txt.bak`

But..

```
f.write("test")
```

gives `Bad file descriptor`

Is there a good way to update the file descriptor?

Should I still call `f.close()` even tho the file has been renamed?

Comment: Why do you open it first and then rename it?

Comment: `f = open('foo.txt','rw')` raises a `ValueError` on my system --perhaps you meant `'r+'`? Is this really the code you're running?

Comment: This has nothing to do with os.rename.  You want mode 'r+'

Comment: @multipleinterfaces`foo.txt` needs to have been created before you can do the read portion of `'rw'`

Comment: @cularis: more of a hypothetical situation that I came across; but maybe if I was reading part of a file to see if I wanted to rename it?

Comment: @pseudosudo `'rw'` is not a valid mode. What platform are you running this on, and under what version of Python?

Comment: @multipleinterfaces interesting, I'm using Python 2.7.1 on Ubuntu

Comment: @pseudosudo then read it, determine if it needs to be renamed, close it and rename it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a function that will rename an open file. Basically, you close, rename, and reopen the file, preserving attributes such as the file position and the mode. Some tweaking of the mode is necessary for the reopen -- if the file's mode is "w", reopening it with the same mode will lose everything in it, so we use "r+" mode in that case when reopening. (This isn't perfect, as it allows read access to the file, which it didn't have before, but it's the best we can do.) You will of course get a completely new `file` object, which is the function's return value.

```
import os

def rename_open_file(fileobj, newname):
    name = fileobj.name
    mode = fileobj.mode.lower()
    posn = fileobj.tell()
    fileobj.close()
    os.rename(name, newname)
    newmode = mode
    if "w" in mode:      # can't reopen with "w" mode since
        newmode = "r+"   # it would empty the file; use "r+"
        if "b" in mode:
           newmode += "b"
    fileobj = open(name, newmode)
    fileobj.seek(posn)
    return fileobj

f = rename_open_file(f, f.name + ".bak")
```

If you have more than one `file` object referencing the open file, this isn't going to help, of course; all other references may break.

Caveat: the file's `name` attribute isn't necessarily the full path, so if you opened the file using a relative path and have changed the directory since opening the file, this isn't going to work. You can write your own `open()` that figures out the file's full pathname at open time (using `os.path.abspath()`) if this is a problem.

Also, the buffer size given when opening the file isn't preserved since this is not recorded anywhere on the file object. Writing your own `open()` can resolve this, too. The easiest way to do this is to subclass `file`.

```
from os.path import abspath
class open(file):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode="r", buffering=-1):
        file.__init__(self, abspath(filename), mode, buffering)
        self.buffering = buffering
```

Then you can add maintaining the buffering to your function:

```
import os

def rename_open_file(fileobj, newname):
    name = fileobj.name
    mode = fileobj.mode.lower()
    posn = fileobj.tell()
    buff = fileobj.buffering
    fileobj.close()
    os.rename(name, newname)
    newmode = mode
    if "w" in mode:      # can't reopen with "w" mode since
        newmode = "r+"   # it would empty the file; use "r+"
        if "b" in mode:
           newmode += "b"
    fileobj = open(name, newmode, buff)
    fileobj.seek(posn)
    return fileobj
```

You can also write a *wrapper* class for a file object, rather than subclassing `file`, and have it pass through all `file`'s method calls to the wrapped object. Then `rename()` can be a method of the wrapper, and do all of the above. Since calling code will keep a reference to the wrapper, it won't need to know that the underlying `file` object is different. I will leave this as an exercise.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

os.rename() works on a pure file name without knowing about any open file objects referencing this file. Therefore you must not rely on the file object working after you did operations on the underlying file, so closing it is probably the right thing to do.