# temp files/directories with custom names?

Tags: python, pytest, temporary-files, python-unittest

How to create a temporary files/directories with user defined names in python. I am aware of [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) . However I couldn't see any function with filename as argument.

Note: I need this for unit testing the glob(file name pattern matching) functionality on a temporary directory containing temporary files rather than using the actual file system.

Comment: Are you aware of the [`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) function?

Comment: I think it names the file randomly. Correct me if am wrong

Comment: The filename may be be random, but since you can find out what it is (`result.name`), you can rename it just like a normal file. You can also control the directory it is created in via the `dir=` argument. Be sure to use `delete=True` if you don't want it deleted as soon as it's closed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This works

Comment: FYI:

`os.rename(r'file path\OLD file name.file type',r'file path\NEW file name.file type')`

Answer (score 6):

If you need to name the temporary files AND directories it looks like you'll have to manage the names and/or creation/deletion yourself.

However, if you just need to control the names of the files you can use `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()` to create a temp directory, created your named files in that directory, and then it will all get deleted when it goes out of context.

Like this:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
    # open your files here
    named_file = open(os.path.join(temp_dir, "myname.txt"), 'w')

    # do what you want with file...

# directory and files get automatically deleted here...
```

Additional example:

```
>>> import tempfile
>>> t = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
>>> print(t)
<TemporaryDirectory '/tmp/tmpqign52ry'>
>>> print(t.name)
/tmp/tmpqign52ry
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. But you don't need `temp_dir.name`, `temp_dir` is all that's required as it's the name of the directory itself.

Comment: The code actually raises an exception `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'`. Have you tested it?

Comment: @Jeyekomon Yes I tested it, see new example above. Behavior might differ with Python version...

Comment: @j314erre I now have used the same Python 3.6.8 and replicated the exception. Please try to actually execute the first example and see the exception. Your second example actually does not verify anything, because while the `TemporaryDirectory()` constructor returns an object, when used as a context manager it returns a plain string. See for yourself or [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory).

Comment: @Jeyekomon thanks you are correct, I fixed the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `open()` with whatever file name you need.

e.g.

```
open(name, 'w')
```

[Open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

Or

```
import os
import tempfile

print 'Building a file name yourself:'
filename = '/tmp/guess_my_name.%s.txt' % os.getpid()
temp = open(filename, 'w+b')
try:
    print 'temp:', temp
    print 'temp.name:', temp.name
finally:
    temp.close()
    # Clean up the temporary file yourself
    os.remove(filename)
```

Or you can create a temp directory using `mkdtemp` and then use `open` to create a file in the temporary directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. when using "mkdtemp", the user is responsible for removing it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884991/how-to-delete-dir-created-by-python-tempfile-mkdtemp/22726782 You may check this

Comment: Thanks. This helped

Answer (score 0):

I almost prefer to write in this convoluted way using `NamedTemporaryFile()`, instead of using `open()`, because I really want to emphasize that this is a tempfile:

```
import tempfile, os

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp_fp:
    os.rename(temp_fp.name, '/tmp/my_custom_name.txt')
    # do stuff here ...

    # do stuff here END ...
    os.rename('/tmp/my_custom_name.txt', temp_fp.name) # finally, rename back
```

We need to rename back because:
[update file descriptor after os.rename()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697972/update-file-descriptor-after-os-rename)

Comment: I'd suggest using a pair of `open` and `os.unlink` over this method. Having to use a "balanced rename" makes this basically the same, except more implicit